# How to map public static IP addresses to Hidden Services?

Tags: vpn, network-configuration, ip-address, transparent-proxy, routers

we want to configure a TOR router to route public static IP addresses to hidden services.

Currently we have the following setup working:

```
VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/10
VirtualAddrNetworkIPv6 [FC00::]/7
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 127.0.0.1:9040
TransPort     [::1]:9040
DNSPort   127.0.0.1:5300
DNSPort       [::1]:5300

iptables  -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.192.0.0/10 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
ip6tables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d FC00::/7      -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
```

My first idea was to use the public static IP-networks with the PREROUTING chain. Updating the IP-addresses every 60 seconds is a no-go as DNSSEC will be used to validate the DNS A/AAAA-record lookups. We also need additional DNS-records (e.g. MX-RRs) which won't work with the TOR resolver.

I already tried

```
MapAddress <hidden service>.onion 10.192.0.4
```

which results in a correct A-RR when VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 is uncommented. But TOR doesn't route the packets.

Thanx for any hint,

Renne

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple task, just to answer the question, here is how you'd do it....

But before you read how, repeat after me:

## "**I should never *actually* do this!**"

Hypothetically, if this was ever actually useful, which it isn't, and assuming your onion is `foo.onion` and your public IP is `1.2.3.4`

torrc like this:

```
TransPort 1.2.3.4:9040 # 
SocksPort 0 # we dont need this
MapAddress 1.2.3.4 foo.onion # connections for our public IP are mapped to the onion
```

Then we use iptables to set some incoming traffic for whatever our chosen port is, say 80, to redirect to the TransPort, for example:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
```

Port 80 on our public IP would be passed into TransProxy, the destination IP `1.2.3.4` in TransProxy would be mapped to `foo.onion` and the communications passed on to `foo.onion` and the response send back to whomever was connecting to `1.2.3.4`.

*Update:*

The `TransPort` can be set once for many ports, the original destination and port are recovered after the `-j REDIRECT` rule through use of `getsockopt()` calls (see `SO_ORIGINAL_DST`), so many destination ports and IPs can map to a single `TransPort` instantiation.

And my issue is that while the server is protected, the users are not receiving any protection from Tor. It constitutes the "SSL Added And Removed Here :¬)" security anti-pattern, as seen in tor2web and similar projects.

---

*P.S. Yes, I am aware I'm a terrible human being for actually answering this query but sometimes you gotta let them shoot themselves in the foot after failing to heed all warnings.*

Comment: For the sake of being complete, why is this a bad idea?

Comment: Because the incoming connection isn't protected at all.

Comment: @canonizing ironize From the view of pure TOR it's bad, of course. We want to create a network of TOR nodes but we still need access for clearnet users. The plan is to use TLS for the clearnet-users and validate the TLS-certificates with [DNS-based Authentication of Named Entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-based_Authentication_of_Named_Entities). That way at least the content is protected for the clearnet users. We will encourage clearnet-users to run their own TOR node, of course. Currently this approach is definitely better than clearnet only. ;-) Is a "TransPort"-Statement necessar